# ¿Error al ejecutar APP ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, react-native

antes que nada muchas gracias, abrí otra pregunta porque no conseguí solución en algunas parecidas que estaban en el foro.

Resulta que creé una APP como React Native y ahora quiero ejecutarla pero no se com ohacerlo porque me da un error. Cree la APP siguiendo estos pasos: https://luismasdev.com/react-native/ y todo se ejecutó muy bien, pero cuando trato de levantar la APP me da un error el siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configuré el archivo gradle.properties y quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\geekha\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Y según yo la ruta esta bien porque es la misma que tengo en el Android Studio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguiste los pasos de instalación tal como lo muestra la documentación? Debes tener en cuenta que esas guías tienden a desactualizarse con el paso del tiempo y la liberación de nuevas actualizaciones de React-Native. Y leyendo la guía que intentas hacer, no veo que definan en ningún lugar la variable de entorno del `ANDROID_HOME` mientras que en la documentación de instalación si sale

Comment: Bueno intentaré ejecutarlo con este https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started a ver si logro.

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: Disculpa no poder comentar, intente varias otras cosas e igual no me funciona. Estoy pensando que es un problema con el servidor de desarrollo o algo asi.